# Icons Missing after update

Tags: icons

since my last restart of my laptop I'm missing all Elementary icons. I'm using eOS 6.

I haven't changed anything, the only thing I'm doing regulary is installing updates from AppCenter.

Is there anyway to reset the icons?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but can you try running `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` in the terminal? You may then need to log out and back in again.

Comment: Thanks, but this was not the issue. Somehow my GTK/Icon Theme was set to Adwaita. I simply ran `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "elementary"` and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "elementary"`, which fixed my issue